# Is there a name for $x^a + y^a = 1$?

Tags: functions

So, I was playing around in Desmos and graphed the equation of a unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then I got curious and decided to graph $x^a + y^a = 1$ and got some interesting patterns. I was wondering if there is a name for this type of equations?

Comment: They are superellipses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere

Comment: The Scandinavian artist and poet Piet Hein liked the one with a=5/2 so much that some people thought to name it after him.